# Unable to install gem mysql2 on RHEL 7 for MariaDB connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mariadb, compatibility

I have a client website running on Ruby that was using MySQL before they decided to upgrade to MariaDB. Due to this, I have to reconfigure the website to use the new database

Server: RHEL 7

Database: MariaDB 10.2

When installing the gem, i got this error.

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180305-7942-1ltzloc.rb extconf.rb
    checking for rb_absint_size()... no

    checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... no
    checking for ruby/thread.h... no
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
    checking for rb_intern3()... yes
    checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
    -----
    Using mysql_config at /usr/bin/mysql_config
    -----
    checking for mysql.h... yes
    checking for errmsg.h... yes
    checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... no
    checking for MYSQL_OPT_SSL_ENFORCE in mysql.h... yes
    checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... no
    checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... yes
    checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
    -----
    Setting libpath to /usr/lib64/
    -----
    creating Makefile

    make  clean
    make
    compiling statement.c
    statement.c: In function ârb_raise_mysql2_stmt_errorâ:
    statement.c:50:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
       VALUE rb_error_msg = rb_str_new2(mysql_stmt_error(stmt_wrapper->stmt));
       ^
    statement.c:57:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
       rb_encoding *default_internal_enc = rb_default_internal_encoding();
       ^
    In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:35:0,
       from statement.c:1:
    statement.c: In function âexecuteâ:
    ./client.h:56:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
       mysql_client_wrapper *wrapper; \
       ^
    statement.c:273:3: note: in expansion of macro âGET_CLIENTâ
       GET_CLIENT(stmt_wrapper->client);
       ^
    statement.c:405:13: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
         VALUE rb_val_as_string = rb_funcall(argv[i], intern_to_s, 0);
         ^
    In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:35:0,
                     from statement.c:1:
    statement.c: In function âfieldsâ:
    ./client.h:56:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
       mysql_client_wrapper *wrapper; \
       ^
    statement.c:481:3: note: in expansion of macro âGET_CLIENTâ
       GET_CLIENT(stmt_wrapper->client);
       ^
    compiling result.c
    result.c: In function ârb_mysql_result_alloc_result_buffersâ:
    result.c:326:40: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         wrapper->result_buffers[i].is_null = &wrapper->is_null[i];
                                            ^
    result.c:328:40: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
         wrapper->result_buffers[i].error   = &wrapper->error[i];
                                            ^
    compiling mysql2_ext.c
    compiling client.c
    In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:35:0,
                     from client.c:1:
    client.c: In function ârb_set_ssl_mode_optionâ:
    ./client.h:56:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
       mysql_client_wrapper *wrapper; \
       ^
    client.c:118:3: note: in expansion of macro âGET_CLIENTâ
       GET_CLIENT(self);
       ^
    client.c:119:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
       int val = NUM2INT( setting );
       ^
    client.c:145:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
    compiling infile.c
    linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [mysql2.so] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/mysql2-0.4.10 for inspection.
    Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/mysql2-0.4.10/gem_make.out
```

I don't know if the error is because of the server or because of the database.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution by OP.*

I was able to install the mysql2 gem by downgrading the MariaDB version to 10.1. Currently, there is an issue regarding this in the gem itself (version 0.4) Source: [Issue #877](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/877), [Issue #932](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/932)
It's either I wait for the next version of the gem or I downgrade the database to a lower version.

mysql2 version 0.4.10 should work with MariaDB 10.2